# Problem with "Security" and the ASP.NET Routing Engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I´m developing an ASP.NET Web Application and want to use the ASP.NET Routing Engine (System.Web.Routing) with it.

My Application works fine in Cassini, but when I start it in  IIS7 (Integrated Application Pool, of course) I always get an error on this line:

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

What could be the reason for this? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Can you give us the complete stack trace? Have you set up your WebConfig to use IIS7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set up your web.config to use IIS7?

See [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/168221.aspx) for more details on how to fix your issue.

Comment: Yeah, this was the solution. Thank you.